# Permission Denied (PublicKey,keyboard-interactive) linux raspberry pi

Tags: linux, git, raspberry-pi

I know there are a ton of questions on this.

I have read almost all of them.

I have also googled this problem to no avail

I attempted to

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:myhubname.git
```

and I get

> Permission Denied (PublicKey,keyboard-interactive)

as a response

I have tried setting the `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` and uncommenting it in `ssh_config`
this didn't work

I have set the `user.name` and `user.email` to what git repo is setup for. They actually have pretty clear instructions so I am at a loss to what I am doing wrong.

I also saw an article that said modify the `authorized_keys` file in ssh which doesn't exist for me. I created it and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you upload your public key to assembla? Does your private key have passphrase encryption on it?

Comment: @Cupcake I know this needs to be done but I can't figure out how

Comment: Which part, uploading your public key or encrypting your private key?

Comment: @Cupcake great question. I am pretty sure I need a private key on my system. Then copy and paste that into the repo settings online

Comment: The private key ***is private***, it must be kept a secret and not be uploaded to a remote server that you do not control. Only ***public*** keys should be uploaded to remote server's that you want ssh access to. A private key should remain secure either on your local machine or some other secure storage device, and can then be used to authenticate yourself with a remote server that has your public key. If your private key is encrypted with a passphrase, you need to decrypt it before you can use it, with something like `ssh-agent`.

Comment: @cupcake so I setup my repo online. There I created a key with a pass phrase. Then my windows machine prompted me for a pass phrase during my first commit so I'm assuming it was using that to send off to the repo. Now I just need to figure out why I can't pull or clone with my rapsberry pi. Based on what you're saying its because I need to create a private/public key and put public key on the server? Why can't my stupid pi just prompt me!!